# if i delete woo-commerce files from my site .would that erase thousands of my products off my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, auto-update

i was updating my `woocommerce` plugin and i got a lot of errors. and now i'm unable to see even my ***wp-admin*** page

...errors are like below:

> Warning: include_once(includes/class-wc-autoloader.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u177161154/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
>   on line 202

the error list is continue till line 245 .
please help me what to do !!

and is it ok to remove and re-install woocommerce pages again through FTP . would that erase thousands of my products off my website?

Comment: changing a file on your server cannot possible affect whatever's stored in your database...

Comment: so..it will not erase my products ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product information is kept in the database so deleting/reinstalling/updaing the plugin files for WooCommerce will have no effect on your product information.

Also, you are referring to the WooCommerce plugin files as the [WooCommerce Pages](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-pages/), which are two different things.

Comment: sorry but what to do...actually i uploaded my all products through woocommerce and now i am having this problem. now i'm asking if i delete wocommerce plugin folder from Plugins will it erase all my products or not ??

Comment: and then i upload fresh woocommerce plugin files ...my products will be there or not ??

Comment: No it will it not delete your products if you do that, as was stated in the answer.

Comment: oh...Thanks a lot brother ....all is well now ..my products and even all settings are same ....i just recovered my website ..thanks bro.